# How to draw horizontal grid lines with relative distances?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to draw horizontal grid lines with distances 1% of previous line position.
For example:
----- (a * 1.01) * 1.01
----- a * 1.01
----- a

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about 1%? That will add so many dense lines that you won't see anything

Comment: Yes. 1%. How many lines depends on minY and maxY.

Comment: But the density will also depend on how large your y axis is. If you plot the lines from lets say y=10 to y=15, and your y axis spans from 0 to 15000, then you won't be able to resolve the difference

Comment: If minY and maxY = 3549 and 3551 1% would be look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you really want the spacing of 1% because that would simply plot a plethora of densely located lines and you would end up seeing a thick band of horizontal lines. Anyhow, here is one way to do so. I am using a spacing of 10% for better representation but you can just replace 1.1 by 1.01

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = x**2 + np.random.normal(0, 1, x.shape)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')

minY = 10
maxY = 160

while minY < maxY:
    plt.axhline(minY, color='gray', linewidth=0.5)
    minY *= 1.1  

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may write your custom locator that sets ticks at a factor of 1.01 of the previous tick location. Such locator could look like

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

class GeomLocator(matplotlib.ticker.IndexLocator):

    def __call__(self):
        if self.axis.axis_name =="x":
            vmin, vmax = self.axis.axes.get_xlim()
        elif self.axis.axis_name =="y":
            vmin, vmax = self.axis.axes.get_ylim()
        return self.tick_values(vmin, vmax)

    def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
        n = int(np.log(vmax/vmin)/np.log(self._base))
        ticks = np.ones(n+2)
        ticks[1:] = self._base
        ticks = vmin * np.cumprod(ticks)
        return ticks
```

Then you may use the minor grid to show the gridlines located by the above locator.

```
x = np.arange(301)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(x)))
y = (y-y.min())/(y.max()-y.min()) * 7000 + 8000

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(GeomLocator(1.01, None))
ax.grid(which="minor", axis="y")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The advantage of this is that in your code you do not need to know the limits of the plot at all and can freely pan or zoom the plot with the grid always keeping up to date.